# Rounding off of Value in Smart Narrative

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I generated a Smart Narrative visual but there are values eg. **10,111,238** and **1,289,652** the problem is the format I need is **10M** and **1.3M** instead. Is there a way where I can Round the value in this feature? Thank you!

[image]

> I added the image for reference.... apology for editing my inquiry.
> Hope you guys still help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: I undid your last edit, in order to save you from backfire "not a question" etc. Adding the picture with a short description is probably helpful. But you should add that info, instead of replacing all of the post with it and shedding all info needed to understand, even identify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a measure to apply the formatting you're wanting to do:

```
Million Format = FORMAT(SUM(tblValues[Value]),"#,##0,,.0M")
```

Step 2: Use that measure in a table or other visual to get 1 row, which can also be aggregated.

Step 3: Convert that visual to smart narrative, which picks up the formatted value

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this info... but I'm not sure how can I apply it to this kind of Smart Narrative